# doubled and tripled sql server results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to create a specific table but some numeric values are doubled or tripled in the result.
here is the situation:

2 tables: Payments and Expenses

```
[Payments]: ID, studentID, Amount, DOP (a row in this table is a payment which a student pays it on DOP (date).
[Expenses]: ID, AmountPaid, TimeStamp (a row in this table is an expense bought such as papers or pens... on a specific date(timestamp)
```

my query is:

```
select
sum(purchases.amount) as 'Income From Students',
sum(Expenses.amountpaid) as 'Expenses',
sum(purchases.amount-expenses.amountpaid) as 'Net Profit',
datename(month,timestamp) as 'Month',
datepart(year,timestamp) as 'Year' 
from expenses,purchases 
group by datename(month,timestamp),datepart(year,timestamp)
```

as the query tells: my table should display for each month and each year the sum of payments, expenses and  net `profit=payments - expenses`.

the problem is, when getting the result, sum(expenses.amountpaid) is always doubled.

so any ideas...

Comment: there are no relations between the tables? e.g. given two rows in Expenses (Jan/2012)(Feb/2012) joined with 4 Rows in Payments will result in 8 Rows view (from expenses,purchases)

Comment: there is no relations between them

Comment: If Nick isn't right(I think he should be) then there is no solution for your problem without changing design.

Comment: @AliMkahal if your problem resolved, then don't forget to accept helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it Guys, After 4 hours of Trying, the query is:

```
select sum(P.Income) as 'Income from Payments',
sum(E.expense) as 'Expenses',
sum(P.Income)-sum(E.expense) as 'Net Profit',
DateName( month , DateAdd( month , IncomeMonth , 0 ) - 1 ) as 'Month'
from
(select sum(payments.amountpaid) as Income,
month(DOP) as IncomeMonth
from payments group by month(dop)) as P,
(select sum(expenses.amountpaid) as Expense,
month(timestamp) as ExpenseMonth
from expenses 
group by month(timestamp))
as E
where
E.Expensemonth=P.IncomeMonth
group by P.IncomeMonth
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to specify the relationship between the two tables.

Something like this, I assume:

```
select
sum(purchases.amount) as 'Income From Students',
sum(Expenses.amountpaid) as 'Expenses',
sum(purchases.amount-expenses.amountpaid) as 'Net Profit',
datename(month,timestamp) as 'Month',
datepart(year,timestamp) as 'Year' 
from expenses,purchases 
WHERE PURCHASES.DOP = EXPENSES.TIMESTAMP /*Add this*/
group by datename(month,timestamp),datepart(year,timestamp)
```

Comment: there is no relationship, just i need to calculate all purchases and expenses within each month, then get (purchases-expenses) from each month.

Comment: There is a relationship, though... the month and year. Have to relate the purchases from each month to the expenses from each month respectively - otherwise, you cannot correctly break out the data by month.

Comment: If you don't return anything from this query, it may be because your DOP and Timestamp columns do not match exactly (to the millisecond even), so you can either floor the date to the month or use:

WHERE YEAR(DOP) = YEAR(Timestamp) AND MONTH(DOP) = MONTH(Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.INCOME,T.EXPENSE,SUM(T.INCOME)-SUM(T.EXPENSE) AS PROFIT 
FROM (SELECT SUM(P.amount) AS Income, SUM(E.amountpaid) AS Expense 
FROM Payments P,Expenses E WHERE P.ID=E.ID  
GROUP BY datename(month, timestamp), datepart(year, timestamp)) AS T;
```

Comment: Column 'T.Income' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: WHERE P.ID=E.ID is unnecessary because no need to relate between the two tables

Comment: @AliMkahal `WHERE P.ID=E.ID is not unnecessary` dude, that is the only reason you are getting the double value. If you don't use that, it will add redundant values. got it ??

Comment: there is no relation, and no need for a relation. I'll try to explain more.

let assume that table 'payments' has:

-record: 100$ 11-10-2012
-record: 150$ 12-10-2012
-record: 140$ 12-11-2012
-record: 120$ 10-12-2012

so, we have here in sum, 250$ in month 10, 140$ in month 11, 120$ in month 12.

the same concept applied to expenses, then i want the result table to display a list of months and sum pf payments, expenses next to each month. as you can conclude, no need for a relationship.